# Need help to read a file in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to read a file and file contains various kinds of data. 
The example of the file type is given below.

```
[CIRCUIT1]
CIRCUITNAME=CIRCUIT1
00.12 12/20 2.3 23.6
00.12 12/20 2.3 23.6
00.42 12/20 2.2 23.3
00.42 12/20 2.2 23.3

[CIRCUIT2]
CIRCUITNAME=CIRCUIT2
00.12 12/20 2.2 26.7
00.12 12/20 2.2 26.7
00.42 12/20 2.2 26.5
00.42 12/20 2.2 26.5
00.42 12/20 2.2 26.5

[AMBIENT]
00.42 12/20 8.6
01.42 12/20 8.6
02.42 12/20 8.6
03.42 12/20 8.7
04.42 12/20 8.8
05.42 12/20 8.6
06.42 12/20 8.7
```

Now, I have defined a function which only returns the 3rd and 4th column of circuit1.
but date and time formats should be returned and will be defined later. But I'm getting index out of range error.

```
def load_ci(filepath):
  fileObj=open(filepath, 'r')
  time_1=[],time_2=[],t=0,ti=0,loadCurrent_1=[],surfaceTemp_1=[],loadCurrent_2=[],surfaceTemp_2=[],ambient=[]
  read=0
  for line in fileObj:
    if not line.strip():
        continue    
    if read==1:
        if '[AMBIENT]' in line:
            read=3
            continue
        elif  'CIRCUITNAME=CIRCUIT2' in line: read=2
        else:
            if line!='\n' and '[CIRCUIT2]' not in line:
                point=line.split(' ')
                t=(float(point[0]))
                ti=int(t)*3600+(t-int(t))*60*100
                time_1.append(ti)
                loadCurrent_1.append(float(point[2]))
                surfaceTemp_1.append(float(point[3]))
    if read==2:
        if '[AMBIENT]' in line:
            read=3
            continue
        elif  'CIRCUITNAME=CIRCUIT2' in line: read=2
        else:
            if line!='\n' and '[CIRCUIT2]' not in line:
                point=line.split(' ')
                t=(float(point[0]))
                ti=int(t)*3600+(t-int(t))*60*100
                time_2.append(ti)
                loadCurrent_2.append(float(point[2]))
                surfaceTemp_2.append(float(point[3]))
    if read==3:
        if line!='\n':
            point=line.split(' ')
            ambient.append(float(point[2]))
    if 'CIRCUITNAME=CIRCUIT1' in line: read=1
return  np.array(loadCurrent_1),np.array(surfaceTemp_1),np.array(loadCurrent_2),np.array(surfaceTemp_2),np.array(ambient),np.array(time_1),np.array(time_2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you detect a line containing [AMBIENT], you need to advance to the next line, while changing your read state to 3.  Add a **continue** statement after **read = 3** at two points in your code where you check for [AMBIENT]

Additionally, change your code checking for [CIRCUIT2] from

```
if line != '\n' and line != '[CIRCUIT2]':
```

to

```
if line != '\n' and '[CIRCUIT2]' not in line:
```

If you want to disregard empty lines, you can add a check at the beginning of your loop like:

```
if not line.strip():
   continue
```

I've reworked your code in the question to break out parsing circuit from ambient data, to simplify state management.  I pass around the file object, utilizing its iteration state to keep track of where we are in the file at any given point.  Sections of the file start with '[...]' and end with a blank line, so I can take advantage of that.  I group all of the circuit data into a dictionary for convenience, but this could be rolled into a full fledged class as well if you wanted to.

```
import numpy as np


def parseCircuit(it, header):
    loadCurrent, surfaceTemp, time = [], [], []
    for line in it:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            break
        elif line.startswith('CIRCUITNAME='):
            name = line[12:]
        else:
            point=line.split(' ')
            h, m = map(int, point[0].split('.'))
            time.append(h * 3600 + m * 60)
            loadCurrent.append(float(point[2]))
            surfaceTemp.append(float(point[3]))
    return {'name': name,
            'surfaceTemp': np.array(surfaceTemp),
            'loadCurrent': np.array(loadCurrent),
            'time': np.array(time)}


def parseAmbient(it, header):
    ambient = []
    for line in it:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            break
        point=line.split(' ')
        ambient.append(float(point[2]))
    return np.array(ambient)


def load_ci(filepath):
    fileObj=open(filepath, 'r')
    circuits = {}
    ambient = None
    for line in fileObj:
        line = line.strip()                  # remove \n from end of line
        if not line:                         # skip empty lines
            continue
        if line.startswith('[CIRCUIT'):
            circuit = parseCircuit(fileObj, line)
            circuits[circuit['name']] = circuit
        elif line.startswith('[AMBIENT'):
            ambient = parseAmbient(fileObj, line)
    return circuits, ambient


print load_ci('test.ci')
```

outputs

```
({'CIRCUIT2': {'loadCurrent': array([ 2.2,  2.2,  2.2,  2.2,  2.2]), 'surfaceTemp': array([ 26.7,  26.7,  26.5,  26.5,  26.5]), 'name': 'CIRCUIT2', 'time': array([ 720,  720, 2520, 2520, 2520])}, 'CIRCUIT1': {'loadCurrent': array([ 2.3,  2.3,  2.2,  2.2]), 'surfaceTemp': array([ 23.6,  23.6,  23.3,  23.3]), 'name': 'CIRCUIT1', 'time': array([ 720,  720, 2520, 2520])}}, array([ 8.6,  8.6,  8.6,  8.7,  8.8,  8.6,  8.7]))
```

Comment: Thanks mtadd. It works really well. Now I want to gather the time format and save this in an array in second format only. What type of conversion is needed to convert hour:minute to seconds?